# Meteor.autorun() not working on client when insert occures

Tags: meteor

i have been knocking my head for 2 days now in that .

am creating a search engine, am creating queries dynamically using Meteor Framwork, the queries are working fine and when i search i can rebind the UI (Table in My Case) with the dynamic data query output.

however if an insert/update/delete operation occures the data object

and the UI (html Table) is not updating.

which means that the template is not re-rendered when the data object changes.

```
Template.search.rendered = function () {


   Meteor.autorun(function() {
        alarmsData = Alarms.find(getSearchSelector($('#searchTxt').val(), $('#startTimeTxt').val(), $('#endTimeTxt').val())).fetch()
        console.log("rendered")
        //alarmsData = Alarms.find({},{sort: {timestamp: "desc"} }).fetch();
        searchControls(alarmsData)
        getConsole(alarmsData, ".console")
        $('#badge').html(alarmsData.length)
   })

}
```

the get console function is just reading the array from teh search and creating an html table (this is working fine)

as for the begining i am creating a simple query as the default for my search. and then am changing this query whenever user changes the search criteria. i can notice that only the first instance of teh data object is kept and tracked for changes, so if the second search criteria resides within the first one, it's updating the UI, if not nothing happenes

i have used Meteor.autorun(function(){}) function however i traced it's execution with console.log and i can see it's no excuting when i insert data in the database for the same collection.

Answer (score 0):

One, I believe you are trying to use [Deps.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_autorun). Also, there is nothing in your autorun that seems to be dependent on a reactive source. Since `alarmsData` is taking a snapshot of data it won't care when Alarms has data changing.

Second, I would probably approach this with a redirect. I would compile my data, and redirect to the same page, allowing the server to handle the querying for me. This easily allows you to jump to this page from anywhere else with a prefilled query in the parameters (because the route would then handle it) and also gives a visual change to the navigation bar when a search has happened (just like every other search engine). You would do something like this on a button click:

```
var query = {},
    path;

query.text = encodeURIComponent($('#searchTxt').val()),
query.start = encodeURIComponent($('#startTimeTxt').val()),
query.end = encodeURIComponent($('#endTimeTxt').val()),

// redirect to current path
path = Router.routes[Router.current().route.name].path({}, {
    query: query
});

Router.go( path );
```

In your router you would just pass the query into your server and route as a data object (assuming you are using [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router)):

```
this.route( "search", {
    path: "/search",
    waitOn: function() {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe( "searchAlarms", _.omit( this.params, "hash" ) ),
        ]
    },
    data: function () {
        return { "query": _.omit( this.params, "hash" ) };
    }
});
```

This will not only give you the query data that was used for the search (in your template) but the server can now handle the search for you! Your Alarms data now holds all of the documents needed to display to the user and you no longer need to subscribe to all your Alarms. This is also great because it is automatically reactive. So if a new Alarm matches your query filter it will automatically be passed down to the client and displayed to the user without needing to setup any extra dependencies/autoruns.

Note though, that if you are subscribing to Alarms elsewhere you will still need to do filtering client-side.

Answer (score 0):

What a strange meteor code…

- The "rendered" code method code is called once you will be rendering the search template
- getSearchSelector($('#searchTxt').val() is not reactive, my advise is to use the session variable to put your search criteria inside and use this same session to inject the find parameters inside.

Are you looking for displaying all the alarms Data ?

```
function getAlarms()
{
    var text = Session.get("text");
    var from = Session.get("start");
    var to   = Session.get("end");
    var filter = getSearchSelector(text, from, to);
    return Alarms.find(filter);
}

Template.search.alarms = function () {
    return getAlarms();
}

Template.search.alarmsCount = function () {
    return getAlarms().count();
}

Template.search.events({
    'keypress input[name=text]' : function(e,o)
    {
        var val = $("input[name= text]").val()
        Session.set("text", val);
    },
    'keypress input[name=start]' : function(e,o)
    {
        var val = $("input[name=start]").val()
        Session.set("start", val);
    },
    'keypress input[name=end]' : function(e,o)
    {
        var val = $("input[name=end]").val()
        Session.set("end", val);
    }
});
```

// And your template will look something like:

```
<template name="search">
    Search alarms
    <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Enter your text here…"/>
    <input type="text" name="start" placeholder="start time"/>
    <input type="text" name="end" placeholder="end time/>

    There is {{alarmsCount}} alarms(s);

    {{#each alarms}}
    Alarm object: {{.}} 
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Guess its Solved it by using Session.set & get, and automatically subscribing to the Serevr and send the dynamic Query.

Check the below Code

Template.zConsole.rendered = function () {

```
    Session.set("obj", getSearchSelector($('#searchTxt').val(), $('#startTimeTxt').val(), $('#endTimeTxt').val()))

    Deps.autorun(function (){
        Meteor.subscribe("dynamicAlarms", Session.get("obj"))
        console.log("Count from AutoRun ==> " + Alarms.find(Session.get("obj")).count())
    })

}
```

on the server

```
Meteor.publish('dynamicAlarms',function (searchObj) {
    return Alarms.find(searchObj)
})
```

& it works perfect with less code.